# Copy data to column

Tags: vba, excel, copy-paste

I have a spreadsheet which contains 22 columns, each cell containing a number between 1 and 80.

I would like to arrange it so that each column contains its own specific value.
This means there will be 80 columns and, on each row, numbers will be shown under its own value.
[image]

Is there anyway to do it with copy/paste and filtering or does it need to be solved by VBA?

Comment: You'd have to show the data, or use a more appropriate language like R - dplyr package. Do you know anything about VBA?

Comment: If you didn't need to move the data, but were willing to set a new set of 80 columns aside for the output (starting at column AA for instance), you could use a formula such as `=IF(IFERROR(MATCH(AA$1,$B2:$W2,0),0)=0,"",AA$1)` in cell A2 and then copy it across the whole range (i.e. AA2:DB1000 or whatever)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `countif` for occurrences of the numbers

[image: countif]